# How to save PostgreSQL schema?

Tags: postgresql, schema

I need to send the schema of a PostgreSQL db to the customer.
How can I do that?
I cannot find it in db directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is better  to use the [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-pgdump.html) utility to export the schema and load back on another machine :

```sh
pg_dump -U postgres --schema-only db_name > file.txt
```

And then you can load it back on another machine/instance with the [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html) utility :

```sh
psql -U postgres db_name < file.txt
```